# Ruby 2.0.0 Openssl, pbkdf2_hmac() function is unimplemented on this machine

Tags: ruby, openssl, ruby-2.0, opensuse

I am using the Ruby [2.0.0 Openssl module](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/PKCS5.html) for one of my encryption/decryption logic.  It works perfectly on my Mac but when i am having the same code on my enterprise SUSE server it throws the below error.

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'openssl'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new 'AES-128-CBC'
=> #<OpenSSL::Cipher:0x007f240fb07888>
irb(main):003:0> cipher.encrypt
=> #<OpenSSL::Cipher:0x007f240fb07888>
irb(main):004:0> iv = cipher.random_iv
=> "\x84R\xCF\x97.\x17\xD1h2\xBB{6\xB8\"\xD1\xC5"
irb(main):005:0> 
irb(main):006:0* pwd = 'some hopefully not to easily guessable password'
=> "some hopefully not to easily guessable password"
irb(main):007:0> salt = OpenSSL::Random.random_bytes 16
=> "#\xBCB\x05\xDE=\x83\xE8IOxR'\xBFRa"
irb(main):008:0> iter = 20000
=> 20000
irb(main):009:0> key_len = cipher.key_len
=> 16
irb(main):010:0> digest = OpenSSL::Digest::SHA256.new
=> #<OpenSSL::Digest::SHA256: e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855>
irb(main):011:0> 
irb(main):012:0* key = OpenSSL::PKCS5.pbkdf2_hmac(pwd, salt, iter, key_len, digest)
NotImplementedError: pbkdf2_hmac() function is unimplemented on this machine
    from (irb):12:in `pbkdf2_hmac'
    from (irb):12
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You might need to upgrade your libssl. It must not be up to date.
See further :

> PKCS5 offers support for PBKDF2 with an OpenSSL::Digest::SHA1-based
>   HMAC, or an arbitrary Digest if the underlying version of OpenSSL
>   already supports it (>= 0.9.4).